# How to create GRUB2 partition in GPT?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a problem that I cannot boot ubuntu and boot repair didnt help me. I read somewhere that when my partiton table is GPT i have to create special partition for a GRUB2, for example Windows created special partition called Windows Boot Manager . Can someone tell my if it's necessary or there is diffrent solution? Im using UEFI . It's possible that im using boot-repair wrong or smth like that. Help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create a partition for GRUB, it was already created from Windows installation process. There already exists an EFI partition to which all the boot loaders have to be installed.
To achieve what you want follow these instructions, they worked in most of the similar cases:

First try to change the boot order in **BIOS (UEFI) settings**.
Select Ubuntu to be the default operating system to boot.

If this is not possible or the GRUB boot menu does not show up when starting your computer,
boot into Windows and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot**.

To disable hibernation open **command prompt as administrator** and execute this command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

After having done this **shutdown** the machine **completely** - do **NOT reboot**!

Then reinstall the GRUB boot loader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media - then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sd*
update-grub
```

Now you can choose which operating system you want to boot from the GRUB boot loader menu.

Note :

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use **GParted**.
The tool is included in the Ubuntu install media.

Comment: I came up with few problems. Is 'reinstalling the grub boot loader' is diffrent action or it's that what u exaplin to me later ? Do i have execute this commands though ubuntu live (form pendrive) or 'normal' ubuntu ? If yes  I cannot boot Ubuntu (I dont even have it in boot menu) , can I use this : http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html ? And last problem , GParted doesnt find my partitions (because of GPT i think) can i use something instead of Gparted ?

Comment: @jakubby : It is the same action but with built-in command line tool (3rd party tools not always work that properly). Do exactly what I wrote : Boot from ubuntu install media ... GParted will find all the partitions (surely only in case they exist) - and, that's got nothing to do with gpt or mbr partition table ! :)

Comment: I did it. After commands it was written that actions was completed ,but nothing change :/ . If u dont have any other ideas maybe i should jest reinstall linux ?

Comment: @jakubby : Yes this is always an option, but before that - please try to change the default system to boot from Windows to ubuntu in BIOS / UEFI  (it must be possible) ! Important is that hibernation and fast boot is disabled in Windows ! - please post back results - I will be back in about 12 hours - good luck my friend ! :)

Comment: I think thtat its disabled since i typed "powercfg /h off" and used this

Comment: I think yes i used this"http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html" (with *.bat option) because i couldnt find it in cotrnol panel. I did evertyhing again , same situation. In boot menu i have only windows boot manager and some two weird positions. I will try to just boot-repair again.

Comment: It's suuuuper weird. When reinstalling ubuntu we have 3 options (erase ubuntu ,partition or smth else) , when i tried to picked 1st one i was informed that my partiton table will be changed, so i picked 3rd , formated ext4 partitoon  and started isntalling it. Everything went good and smooth. I rebboted computer and then ... I dont have 'grub menu', where i can pick OS . I'm really really close to just give up and change my partition table from GPT to MSDOS. I changed it in the first place ,because I read that GPT >> MSDOS .

Comment: @jakubby - This would be an option as well ... but then you will have to 1. reinstall Windows and then afterwards  2. reinstall ubuntu ! :)

Comment: And after reinstalling windows , should i turn off hibernation and fast startup or its not necessary ?

Comment: @jakubby : yes. it is absolutely necessary - otherwise the PC would always start in hibernate mode ! :)

Comment: And its done , everything ok now. Ty for help and patience !